# How to add a scrollbar inside JLabel? using <html> tag I can wrap text but not able to set height

Tags: java, html, css, swing, jlabel

I want to show 1000 chars inside JLabel, using  tags I am able to wrap text but not able to add scrollbar using overflow, even the height property is not working, width works but not height

Comment: Try putting the label into a scrollpane instead of of the other way round.

Comment: *I want to show 1000 chars inside JLabel* - why? Are you doing special formatting? If you are just displaying text you can use a JTextArea. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating your problem so we can see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: its an XHTML that supports div, label tags only which internally are JPanel, JLabel. Cant use JTextArea.

Comment: The framework binds variable to a label tag and I have limited space to show all 1000 chars. Basically, its a customer notes section that I want to show on screen

Comment: *"Cant use JTextArea."* .. Why? Note that the more other people understand the requirement and constraints, the more they are able (& willing) to help.

Comment: BTW: Tip: Add @Thomas (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.